# Creating Quality Profile in SonarQube via XML doesn't import all existing Rules?

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, maven-2, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I installed a local SonarQube instance and want to analyse a project with a custom Quality Profile, however when I import a Quality Profile from an XML-File, it contains only 423 Rules, while 516 Rules are already defined in the XML-File 
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding the required repository. The quality profile and its rules are associated with repository. if you dont have the required repo, the rules under that repo will be skipped while importing.

You need to check with each Quality profile to see which are repo's missing. And then add them from http://localhost:9000/updatecenter. After the repo is added, all rules will be imported. Hope it helps.

Regards